# Finding the max count of months in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries, referenced as city_file, that include several key value pairs. I am looking to use `Counter` to find the most common month for the `'Start Time`' key which is provided in `'2017-06-01 11:45:35'` form.

How would I go about using `datetime` to convert the values of `'Start Time'` to only return the count of months rather than the full `'Start Time'` value and pass that into the `Counter` (ex: `2017-06-01 11:45:35` as `'January'` and gives the total count of January start times).

I have this so far:

```
c = Counter((month['Start Time']) for month in city_file)
```

and it counts each value as unique values for each `'Start Time'` rather than counting the number of rides in January.

input:

```
city_file = [
    {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:00:36', 'Trip Duration': '356', 'User Type': 'Customer'}, 
    {'Start Time': '2017-01-01 00:00:36', 'Trip Duration': '356', 'User Type': 'Customer'}, 
    {'Start Time': '2017-02-01 00:00:36', 'Trip Duration': '356', 'User Type': 'Customer'}
]
```

expected output:

```
[(January: 2), (February: 1)]
```

Comment: It would be great if you could update your question with sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the month you can extract that part of the string like:

#### Code:

```
c = Counter(month['Start Time'][5:7] for month in city_file)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import calendar
from collections import Counter
dates = (
    '2017-05-01 11:45:35',
    '2017-06-01 11:45:35',
    '2017-06-01 11:45:35',
    '2017-07-01 11:45:35',
)
city_file = [{'Start Time': d} for d in dates]

c = Counter((calendar.month_name[int(month['Start Time'][5:7])] for month in city_file))

print(c)
```

#### Results:

```
Counter({'June': 2, 'May': 1, 'July': 1})
```

Comment: @ron_kuby You can make exact output by  calling `list(c.keys())`(where `c` is the counter object in the answer).